# Gstreaming over http using Python and openCV

Tags: python, http, opencv, gstreamer

I have a stream from an IP camera that I feed for image processing with openCV. 
Currently, once the image is processed, I'm outputting it using `cv2.imshow()` in a popup window as shown below.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://76.75.8.111/mjpg/video.mjpg')

while True:

    hasframe, image = cap.read()

    #image=cv2.resize(image, (620, 480)) 
    # do some more image processing here.

    cv2.imshow(window_title, image)
```

I want to send the processed image to a specific web address by piping the output of the above code to cv2's VideoCapture method. For that purpose, I might end up using gstreamer pipelines but I could not find a python tutorial.

```
def main():
    global capture
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture()    #gstreamer pipelines here?
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320); 
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);

    try:
      server = HTTPServer(('',9090),CamHandler) 
      print("server started")
      server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      capture.release()
      server.socket.close()
```

Please help or point me to where I can find similar implementation.

Comment: what is the problem ? What do you have in `CamHandler` ? I made only streaming PyGame's image (PyGame server to PyGame client) using socket and own protocol: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/socket-send-receive-image

Comment: furas, the problem has been solved - I didn't need to use gstreamer at all. Thank you for sharing your streaming implementation. The `CamHandler` is a class in this module https://github.com/berak/opencv_smallfry/blob/master/mjpg_serve.py